# Communication from SKScene to UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm using `Google AdMob` and to present ads, I do so from the `ViewController`. Right now, I have a button in my `GameScene` that is supposed to tell the `ViewController` to display the ads.

At first, I tried delegation, but that didn't work since `SKScene` already has a delegate, but then I stumbled upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28184461/how-to-call-method-from-viewcontroller-in-gamescene/30861164) that showed a way for the `SKScene` to call a method in its `ViewController`. The answers seems sketchy, though, as the `SKScene` holds a reference to its `ViewController`. My understanding, as well as according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025147/mvc-is-it-ok-for-views-to-keep-reference-to-their-view-controller-and-handle-d), was that this is bad practice, assuming that in my case, the `SKScene` is the `View` in the MVC structure.

So how should I notify the `ViewController` of events occurring in the `SKScene`?

Comment: Hint: notification.

Comment: @ElTomato I was going to use NSNotificationCenter but I thought it should only be used if I was broadcasting to more than one thing

Comment: You can use NotificationCenter however you like. There's no rulebook for it. In my app, I use delegates when there's only one listener, but for all the other cases, where there are multiple listeners, I just use NotificationCenter. Works great, and I haven't been struck by lightning yet. (Also, I think Apple advises that you use NotificationCenter instead of NSNotificationCenter, unless you need pass-by-reference semantics? Something like that. Maybe have a look before you start implementing your notifications.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48964872/8948781) which describes how to communicate SKScene with UIViewController using [delegate pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html).